# Why does PHP echo return an incomplete link?

Tags: php

So I have the following code:

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$Website.$Elements[2].'/'.$Row["povezava"].'" class="leftMenuArticlesInactive"></a><li>';
```

1. $Website contains: http://www.somesite.com/test/
2. $Elements[2] contains: sometext
3. $Row["povezava"] contains: sometext2

All variables have nothing but letters in them.

Now my problem.
If I try to echo the following I get:

```
// I'm missing "sometext":
http://www.somesite.com/test/sometext2
// Should be like this:
http://www.somesite.com/test/sometext/sometext2
```

If I do print_r($Elements) I can see that $Elements[2] is "sometext".

Why can't I echo $Elements[2] along with a few other variables?

edit: added more code

```
$Website = 'http://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . '/' . $Elements[1] . '/';

function ShowMenuOfParent($Parent, $Spacing) {
    $Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `izdelki_meni` WHERE `stars` = '$Parent';");
    if(mysql_num_rows($Query) != 0) {
        while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Query)) {
            $s = '<li><a href="'.$Website.$Elements[2].'/'.$Row["povezava"].'" class="leftMenuArticlesInactive">';
            for($i = 0; $i < $Spacing;$i++) {
                $s .= '&nbsp;';
            }
            $s .= $Row["ime"].'</a></li>';
            echo $s;
            ShowMenuOfParent($Row["id"], $Spacing + 8);
        }
    }
}

$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `izdelki_meni` WHERE `stars` = 0;");
if(mysql_num_rows($Query) != 0) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Query)) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$Website.$Row["povezava"].'" class="leftMenuArticlesActive">'.$Row["ime"].'</a></li>';
        if($Elements[2] == $Row["povezava"]) {
            ShowMenuOfParent($Row["id"], 8);
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Have you proved to yourself those variables contain the values you expected? what does print_r show?

Comment: Post the exact output of print_r($Elements)

Comment: Try also `var_dump()` which always output something!

Comment: Can you post here the result of print_r($Elements)?

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any error in the above code ... are u sure the array contains the correct values . Can you please post the O/P of print_r($Elements)

Comment: Please look into `printf()`... this code is painful to try to read.

Comment: @Erik: Asking that question already shows that you suspect that this can't be true. If you're that far, why don't you try to find the error you made instead?

Comment: var_dump() showed: string(7) "test-po"

Comment: Well it looks like $Elements[2] does not actually contain what you expect it to contain. What happens when you print $Elements[2] separately? Also, what do you see when you var_dump() $Elements?

Comment: @hakre Because I've been struggling with this for the past 15 minutes can't find the problem, whenever I echo the variable it returns something, but using it in that line just skips it.

Comment: @objectified doesn't matter what it contains when I echo it in that sentence I get "nothing" back, it should be something ... anything...

Comment: @Erik: Debugging can be daunting, that's normal. If you struggle too long with one problem, it often helps to leave it aside broken, grab a cup of tea, and stop with guessing and trying. Then, with the brain a bit refrehed, start locating the cause of the problem without any sort of guessing. Straight down to the point of error. Locate and eliminate it. For that there are tools like a step-debugger with which you can monitor how your program runs while it runs and how variables change while it runs, e.g. xdebug: http://xdebug.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't I echo $Elements[2] along with a few other variables?

Actually, `echo` can do that, so only this part of your question remains unresolved:

> Why can't I?

What you can and what you can not often depends on what you've learned so far to do. As learning is subjective, it's hard to answer that question by somebody else than you. But probably you can add more information what especially hinders you to understand your actual problem so others can better assist you.

---

The information you provide with your question is factually wrong. I can understand you have a problem and you would like to fix it, but what you actually do is that you make your problem bigger than it is by posting it here as an invitation for others to even do more guessing. I mean 10 persons are able to guess more than one person. So the way you ask is actually counter-productive and not helpful. Both for yourself as anybody else.

Instead of guessing you need to start to actually proof things step by step. Start with your own expectation:

> Now my problem. If I try to echo the following I get:

```
// I'm missing "sometext":
http://www.somesite.com/test/sometext2
// Should be like this:
http://www.somesite.com/test/sometext/sometext2
```

And the code you've posted that is related to the output is:

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$Website.$Elements[2].'/'.$Row["povezava"].'" class="leftMenuArticlesInactive"></a><li>';
```

You write that `$Website` ends with `/test/`, and additionally there is a slash in the output string (`.'/'.`), however the output itself does not even contain that extra string according to you:

```
http://www.somesite.com/test/sometext2
```

And that is already regardless what `$Elements` or `$Row` contains. Start thinking first, *you* need to analyze why that happens, and others can not help your with that, because we don't have your software and your data to debug it. With some time you will learn your own best ways to find the mistakes you do.

Take the time to setup yourself the xdebug debugger and step through your code then. It helps you to locate errors very quickly. And not only this time but also in the future.

Comment: @Erik: Not really, however, I've edited my answer as well, I hope it makes some sense.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be printing unescaped text inside an HTML attribute that's part of a URL. My educated guess is that you are inspecting the scripts's output as the browser renders it, e.g. by hovering the mouse and reading the tooltip. Instead, use your browser's "View Source" feature to see the exact output.

Additional tips:

1. [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) is by far the best built-in function for debugging purposes. All other functions either cast variables to strings or can hide some important information.
2. Abort the script with [die()](http://php.net/die) or [exit()](http://php.net/exit) right after the offending line to ensure the output is not altered later.

Comment: Let me explain a bit more. I have an .htaccess that redirects all data in form of "subpage1/subpage2/subpage3// etc. into index.php. When index receives the data I explode it with "/" and store all the data into $Elements. When I var_dump i get "array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(7) "izdelki" [2]=> string(7) "test-po" }". You can see here that $Elements[2] is set and equals "test-po". When I try to use that in a sentance I posted above I got nothing out. And the variable is never changed in index. What could be wrong?

Comment: I have the impression that you are debugging the complete application at once, instead of the single line that's supposedly failing. If you var_dump `$Elements` right before the line, `die()` right after it and go to "View-> Page Source" you'll see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

PHP sometimes has a hard time with concatenation on multiple variables in a line (back to back). This depends on the server setup. You could try echoing using one of the following:

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$Website.''.$Elements[2].'/'.$Row["povezava"].'" class="leftMenuArticlesInactive"></a><li>';

echo '<li><a href="'.$Website;
echo $Elements[2].'/'.$Row["povezava"].'" class="leftMenuArticlesInactive"></a><li>';

echo '<li><a href="',$Website,$Elements[2],'/',$Row["povezava"],'" class="leftMenuArticlesInactive"></a><li>';
```

Comment: A "hard time"? How operators work (and even expressions) are 99,999% predictable in PHP, there is only very very very very limited undefined behaviour.

Comment: I work off of 4 different servers. The one that is a shared server through a hosting provider I cannot concat "text" . $var1 . $var2 . "text". On servers I have setup my self and manage, I can do it.